# DialogViewController how to hide back button text

Tags: ios

I am using the DialogViewController and when I navigate to an HtmlElement the new view is showing the back button with back button text. Is it possible to hide the text from all childviews when navigating within a DialogViewController?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using Xamarin. I extracted this from their docs:

> - If the ViewController.Title has not been set, the button text will be    Back.
> - If the ViewController.Title has been set, the button will display the same text. In the sample code when the Title property is set and then the ViewController ‘pushed’, the back button will contain the same value: Home.

Source: [Change the Back Button](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/change_the_back_button/)